# Eclipse | Dynamic Web Project | JAR File

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, manifest.mf

By adding `JAR` files in `\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib` folder, everything is working fine. But I don't want to do that. I don't want to add my JAR files in my project folder rather I want to keep the `JAR` files in separate folder (Out of Project folder) and access the files. I tried by adding in classpath but it's not working. May I know how to add JAR file path in `\WebContent\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF` file ?

Comment: What's the error message for "It's not working"? Did you go into your web project's Deployment Assembly property page and flag those jars as needing to be deployed?

Comment: By adding the jar files in classpath, while running the application its showing that the Class is not loaded but ClassNotFound exception occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the jars here:

Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs

Comment: Tried adding in the path what you said, but ClassNotFound Exception occurs

Comment: Which class you getting this error and what jar are you adding?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a maven project. you can solve it by creating multiple modules in a project and every module set it as a `<packaging>jar</packaging>` .

you can add pom.xml in the main module as below

```
<modules>
        <module>XXX</module>
</modules>
```